# How to run multiple chrome windows that are hidden

Tags: python, session, cookies, queue, element

Hello I am currently working on a script where I want to open several different chrome windows (with all different cookies) there is a way to do this manually (u create a new user so in your chrome you have person1 person2 person3 etc..... I want a way to open (ALOT or be able to specify how many windows I want open with `input` or `raw_input` and have all those windows open to a certain url and only show up when a certain condition is shown)

For example:
On certain websites they release product and they may get alot of people on there website and so they create a queue where they select random people to access the website at certain time (and the more windows you have open (with diffrent cookies so they cant get tracked) and then show up on the computer when they get threw so if a certain element is found (something like that)

Can anyone help me out and lmk if there is a way to do this??

THANK YOU

Comment: What's your *specific* question?

Comment: @KlausD. How do I open multiple chrome windows that are hidden and only show up when a certain element on the website is found